# How to calculate area of polygon using cartesian coordinates in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, math, equation

How to write javascript code of math equation cross product to calculate area ? 
  Cross product to calculate area is like this link bellow :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html
Any example?

Comment: Why don't you try yourself? If you know js then try this way. How can you get the value of x1,x2,......,xn and y1,y2,.....yn? First determine this. If you have the value, then the solution is easy. Run a for loop from 1 to n and do the calculation you need. But if you are a non-programmer and in need of that code anyway, than we can help you.

Comment: Yapp,, i'm a geodesy student,, n newbie in javascript code to build some program in my webgis.. So i need your help to write the code anyway..

Comment: I think contour integration is a more general solution.  It'll work for arbitrary irregular shapes, even those with internal holes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and mention if any explanation is needed. I haven't test it, so try for several inputs and be sure it works correctly.  ( Of course this can be efficient, but i wrote like that you can easily understand )

```
<script>       
    var n = prompt("Please enter the value of n in your equation:");
    var arrayOfx=[], arrayOfy = [];

    for (var i= 1;i <= n;i++ ){

        temp = prompt("Please enter the value of x"+ i +" in your equation:");
        arrayOfx.push(temp)

        temp = prompt("Please enter the value of y"+ i +" in your equation:");
        arrayOfy.push(temp)
    }

    area = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < n-1;i++){

        area +=arrayOfx[i]* arrayOfy[i+1] - arrayOfy[i]* arrayOfx[i+1] 
    }

    if (n >2){
        area += arrayOfx[n-1]*arrayOfy[0]- arrayOfy[n-1]*arrayOfx[0]

    }

    alert("The area is "+ area/2);

</script>
```

The negative area will show negative value. You can add Math.abs(area) if you want positive always.